# Press any key to continue not working?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd, executable

Okay, I'm running an executable .jar file, and something kinda funky is happening.  The jar opens the command prompt (Windows 7, cmd) but that's supposed to happen.  After everything finishes I get the:

> Press any key to continue . . .

However, when I press a key, it just keeps the command prompt open, instead of closing it.

In my code, I have this to run the command prompt:

```
String fileName = "File Location";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/k","start",
            "cmd","/k",fileName});
p.waitFor();
```

Is there something in this I could modify to fix it so that way the "Press any key to continue" actually allows me to exit without having to type "exit" next?

Edit: There's a pause at the end of my.  Is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start a new cmd prompt and execute something in it.

How on earth do you expect the cmd to *know* that it should terminate after executing the command? You have to put an "exit" in the script you are running if you want the cmd to close.

Or try running the cmd with option /C.

Comment: The only reason I don't have it exiting right away is so that the user  can view the information that the command prompt is displaying

Comment: @SamuelBauer How does that prevent you from correcting the problem as answered?

Comment: Misread what you wrote.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I get confused /c and /k every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following at the end of you code should exit the window

```
System.exit(1);
```

Comment: Didn't do anything for me.  :/

Comment: When you press any key. What happens? Does it repeat or go back to where you can type. Also are you starting the app from batch?

Comment: The jar is calling the batch, but the problem has been resolved now.  Thanks!